# C++ Newbie in Linker Hell

Tags: c++, g++, linker-errors

Using g++ and having linker errors.  I have a simple program in split into two modules: main.cpp and Dice.h Dice.cpp.

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Dice.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    int dieRoll = Dice::roll(6);
    std::cout<<dieRoll<<std::endl;

    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Dice.h:

```
#ifndef DieH
#define DieH

namespace Dice
{
    int roll(unsigned int dieSize);
}

#endif
```

Dice.cpp:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "Dice.h"

namespace Dice
{
    int roll(unsigned int dieSize)
    {
        if (dieSize == 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        srand((unsigned)time(0));
        int random_int = 0;
        random_int = rand()%dieSize+1;

        return random_int;
    }
}
```

I compile and link these files using g++ as follows:

```
g++ -o program main.cpp Dice.cpp
```

And I get the following linker error:

```
Undefined symbols:
"Dice::roll(int)", referenced from:
  _main in ccYArhzP.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm completely flummoxed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Works here.  Are you sure that's exactly the command you're using?

Comment: actually I just tried it, and it compiles and runs just fine (using the steps you described exactly)

Comment: Side Note:, srand() is usually called once in the program, not each time you call the function `roll()`. Solution: add a function `Dice::srand()`, and call it in main once.

Comment: Also, if we're going that route, prefer to use `static_cast` over C-style casts. Your line would read: `srand(static_cast<unsigned>(time(0));` Also, if you insert spaces: `rand() % dieSize + 1;` it becomes much more readable.
`

Comment: I'm sure that's the command I'm using.  Its copied from the terminal window and pasted here.  Ran it again just to see whether the crack I've been smoking really has worn off. Still getting the same linker errors.  FWIW I'm running gcc 4.2.1 in mac os x 10.6.1.

Comment: Have you checked to make sure your header files really contain what you think they do? Close all your editors down, go to the files, and check them, making sure function signatures match.

Comment: Also, many thanks for the coding tips Amro and GMan!!

Comment: Follow GMan's advice - I can repro the error if dice.h has a missing `unsigned`: "int roll( int dieSize);"

Comment: GMan - you're the man.  Closed all editors and reopened the files.  Found and error in Dice.h.  I corrected the argument to roll in Dice.h: from int roll(int dieSize) to int roll(unsigned int dieSize).  Links and runs!

Comment: Excellent, you can now carry on (my wayward son).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your code is well-formed.

Ensure that your don't have conflicting file names, the files exist and contain what you think they do. For example, perhaps you have a `Dice.cpp` that's empty, and you're editing a newly created one somewhere else.

Minimize possible discrepancy by removing unnecessary files; only have `main.cpp`, `dice.h`, and `dice.cpp`.

Your errors do not match your code: `"Dice::roll(int)"`. Observe that this is looking for an `int`, but your functions take an `unsigned int`. Make sure your header matches.

---

Try the following:

```
g++ main.cpp -c
```

This will generate `main.o`, the compiled but not-linked code for main. Do the same with `dice.cpp`:

```
g++ dice.cpp -c
```

You now have two object files that need to be linked together. Do so with:

```
g++ main.o dice.o
```

And see if that works. If not, do the following:

```
nm main.o dice.o
```

This will list all the available symbols in an object, and should give you something like this:

```
main.o:
00000000 b .bss
00000000 d .ctors
00000000 d .data
00000000 r .eh_frame
00000000 t .text
00000098 t __GLOBAL__I_main
00000069 t __Z41__static_initialization_and_destruction_0ii
         U __ZN4Dice4rollEj
         U __ZNSi3getEv
         U __ZNSolsEPFRSoS_E
         U __ZNSolsEi
         U __ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev
         U __ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev
         U __ZSt3cin
         U __ZSt4cout
         U __ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_
00000000 b __ZStL8__ioinit
         U ___gxx_personality_v0
         U ___main
00000055 t ___tcf_0
         U _atexit
00000000 T _main

dice.o:
00000000 b .bss
00000000 d .data
00000000 t .text
00000000 T __ZN4Dice4rollEj
         U _rand
         U _srand
         U _time
```

C++ mangles function names, which is why everything looks so weird. (Note, there is no standard way of [mangling names](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling), this is how GCC 4.4 does it).

Observe that `dice.o` and `main.o` refer to the same symbol: `__ZN4Dice4rollEj`. If these do not match, that's your problem. For example, if I change part of `dice.cpp` to be this:

```
// Note, it is an int, not unsigned int
int roll(int dieSize)
```

Then `nm main.o dice.o` produces the following:

```
main.o:
00000000 b .bss
00000000 d .ctors
00000000 d .data
00000000 r .eh_frame
00000000 t .text
00000098 t __GLOBAL__I_main
00000069 t __Z41__static_initialization_and_destruction_0ii
         U __ZN4Dice4rollEj
         U __ZNSi3getEv
         U __ZNSolsEPFRSoS_E
         U __ZNSolsEi
         U __ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev
         U __ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev
         U __ZSt3cin
         U __ZSt4cout
         U __ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_
00000000 b __ZStL8__ioinit
         U ___gxx_personality_v0
         U ___main
00000055 t ___tcf_0
         U _atexit
00000000 T _main

dice.o:
00000000 b .bss
00000000 d .data
00000000 t .text
00000000 T __ZN4Dice4rollEi
         U _rand
         U _srand
         U _time
```

Note, this gives two different symbols. `main.o` looking for this: `__ZN4Dice4rollEj` and `dice.o` containing this `__ZN4Dice4rollEi`. (The last letter differs).

When trying to compile these mismatched symbols (with `g++ main.o dice.o`), I get:

```
undefined reference to `Dice::roll(unsigned int)'
```

Comment: Checked and double checked.  Only three files in the directory.  The program compiles, but fails to link.  Same error as originally stated.

Comment: That's pretty wild. I'm going to write up some steps we'll take.

Comment: I'd suggest compiling the two files separately, running nm on their .o files and piping that through c++filt. main.o should contain an undefined symbol for your Dice::roll(?) and Dice.o should contain a defined one for possibly a different Dice::roll.

Comment: Many thanks.  I made an error in Dice.h.  Please see GMan's posts above.

Comment: Oh, I had just finished showing you how to look at symbols too :) You certainly saw more of C++ than I did when I started.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're calling `Dice::roll(int)` and you wrote a `Dice::roll(unsigned int)` function. The function it's looking for doesn't actually exist (internally, argument types of a function matter just as much as its name; this is how overloading works). Try passing it an unsigned int (`6u` for example) and see if that works. Alternately, your header file may not match in both files, and main.cpp thinks your function takes a (signed) int.

Comment: That would not make a difference. The compiler can implicitly cast.

Comment: I think Ken just didn't copy-and-paste his header, but rather rewrote it from scratch here, and that's the problem with `int`/`unsigned int`.

Comment: It can, but given the error message it doesn't appear to be trying that (and given the separate compilation units, how would the first one know to try two separate versions of the symbol?). Signed and unsigned types in g++ at least are mangled differently (the unsigned ones typically get a U on them) so it seems like it could be a problem.

Comment: Passing it a different type would not change it though, because the compiler would still assume that the function takes an `int`, and cast it back to what the presumably missing function is expecting.

Comment: I never realized it was that smart. I guess you learn something every day :) I updated the post with the only other explanation that makes sense to me.

Comment: Pavel - you're right on the money.  I made an error in Dice.h.  please see Gman's post above.

Comment: GCC is very smart - especially the latest 4.4.x release track. It surprises me every single day by outputting code that looks like as if it was output by an experienced assembly programmer.

Answer (score 0):

I know you don't want to hear anything like it, but "It works for me!".

Your errors look suspiciously old - what version of GCC are you using? This look like GCC 2.x!
Also, try to type dieRoll in main.cpp as unsigned, that might resolve namespace problem on this old compiler.

Comment: I'm using gcc version 4.2.1.  Platform is Mac OS X 10.6.1.  Using the command prompt instead of XCode.

Comment: Apple truly made GCC 4 look like GCC 2.95. GCC's error messages are nothing like those today.

Comment: Oh that's right, that's not gold, that's odcctools! They look like a fork of a really old binutils. Shame on me for taking binutils+gcc for granted!